# duplicate output in multithreading java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multithread programming. The code does not do what I want :

```
public class Test {
    static int i;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for(i = 0; i<10 ;i++) {
             executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                 public void run () {
                     System.out.println(i);
                 }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

output : 
2
4
3
4
2
6
6
8
9
10

I expect it to output something like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 with or without order.
My question is what i can do to get my expected output, and how to make them in order.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are printing what `i` happens to be when the thread runs.  I am surprised it is not just `10` every time as the thread would take some time to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a class that implements `Runnable` and copy the static field into an instance field with a constructor:

```
executor.execute(new MyRunnable(i));


class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
     int i;

     public MyRunnable(int i) {
         this.i = i;
     }

     // run method
 }
```

This guarantees that each thread has its own unique integer with exactly the same order of `i` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for response, I am just wondering what is better way to do so, your answer or ka4eli's answer

Comment: I think both boil down to almost the same compiled code therefore same performance. If I'm not wrong though, the other answer requires Java 8 to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass static `i` to `run`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++){
         int x = i;
         executor.execute(new Runnable(){
         public void run (){
             System.out.println(x);
         }
     });
    }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comments, once I remove i, i is not visible to runnable.

Comment: sorry, my fail. Updated the answer.